# Scroll View with Image Resizing Error

Tags: ios, swift

The images scroll,however, they are not scaled to fit in the scroll view. I tried adding

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

but this just made it more tiny.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

```
class DonateViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainscrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var model: [DonationFund]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "333"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "111"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "222")]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainscrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainscrollView.frame.height)

        mainscrollView.contentSize.width = mainscrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainscrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    }
```

Comment: Try `.scaleAspectFill`

Comment: Try adding a contentview on top of scrollview, on that add imageviews